# handle right click in selenium/nide for IE in java

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I am trying to right click on a specific element as it open a custom menu, thing is, IE doesnt do the right click. (it work with firefox) also native event are disabled for IE

(using selenide:`elem.contextClick();`)

i assume either i have done something wrong or the action is broken and in that case i need to bypass it and i tried to call some js code:
`executeJavaScript("document.querySelector('cssSelector').???()");`

in my case here's the event associated with this element as seen in firefox html inspector(can't show it code, sorry about that)

[image]

**to resume:**

how do i right click on a specific element in selenium/nide and if it is broken, how do i call the event with js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, my bad, my problem was deeper than that but i found the solution:

i had to use a custom jquery event for other reasons so here's how it look

```
cmd="$(cssselector).trigger(jQuery.Event('mousedown',{button:2}))"
executeJavaScript(cmd);
```

if no custom event is required (aka when the page you're testing is well made -_-)

```
cmd="$(cssselector).trigger('mousedown')"
executeJavaScript(cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, it seems that the oncontextmenu property support IE browser, but The contextmenu attribute only works in Firefox.

> how do i right click on a specific element in selenium/nide and if it
>   is broken, how do i call the event with js

Please refer to the following code, use the mousedown event to handle the left/right click event, then using a button click event or directly create an event and call the mouseDown function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mouseDown(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        e = e || window.event;
        switch (e.which) {
            case 1: leftClick(); break;
            case 2: middleClick(); break;
            case 3: rightClick(); break;
        }
    }

    function leftClick() {
        alert("left click event");
    }
     function middleClick() {
        alert("middle click event");
    }
     function rightClick() {
        alert("right click event");
    }

    function triggerClick(e) {
        //trigger the right click event.
        var event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.which = 3;
        mouseDown(event);
    }
</script>


<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <a id="btnSubmit" href="#" onmousedown="mouseDown(event);">Click Here</a> <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnTriggger" value="Trigger Button" onclick="triggerClick(event);" />
</body>
```

[Comment] The body's oncontextmenu property is used to prevent the browser contextmenu.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

When using the selenium webdriver, on the web site, you could add a hidden button, and use above code to trigger the right click event from the hidden button click event, then, after finding the hidden button from the webdriver, you could call the click method to trigger the right click event.

Besides, you could also use the [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html) to execute JavaScript through Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i will go back to you once i've tested it :)

Comment: unluckily this doesnt work but i have edited my question to add my latest discoveries, do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

**First, instantiate an Actions class:** in your code.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
```

example code right Click.

```
 WebElement btnElement = driver.findElement(By.id("rightClickBtn"));
 actions.contextClick(btnElement).perform();
```

Comment: your answer is interesting but is it really a different method or is it just the same method but called in a different way?